# Inconsistent behaviour with DOM access in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting this really weird behavior with dynamically created element properties.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 // --- more dom manipulation ---
 this.viewport = document.createElement('div');
 // --- more dom manipulation ---
 this.wrapper.parentNode.insertBefore(this.viewport, this.wrapper); // <-- element inserted into DOM before checking width
 console.log(this.viewport);
 console.log(this.viewport.offsetWidth);
}
```

I create a div element, insert it and read it's properties. Only the first console log properly prints the offsetWidth (884 on my screen) but when I try to print offsetWidth directly, it is 0.

All DOM alterations work properly and produce the intended effects on screen except this programmatic access to dimensions.

[image: offsetWidth ffs !!]

Note: I know that direct dom manipulation is not good for workers or SSR but that's a bridge I'll cross later. besides, these UX components get rendered properly pre-manipulation.

Comment: That's correct behavior.You see mutated property in the first console since the result of `console.log(this.viewport)` will be executed once you click on object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3btfmaen/

Comment: Tried re-querying after insertion, still 0. `console.log(document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('.app-carousel-viewport').offsetWidth);` Do I need to await till the DOM renders it completely?

Comment: In your example you have mutated the value after console log, but in my code I have clearly inserted the element BEFORE checking it's width.

Comment: Create an example on stackblitz so that i can help you

Comment: You clearly inserted element but your images haven't loaded yet. Try setting width and height attributes on img tag

Comment: No I have css classes setting width to 100% on that element and all others around it. But yeah I think it's a css misconfig somewhere. I got the value to update but it's not grabbing 100% of the size. Thanks though I should have it from here

Comment: lmao..fixed. I didn't have width set on the root container which I added after I made the carousel. Thanks, you got me thinking on the right track.